# Display value of array based on values of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays

```
     var arry1 = [1,2,3]
     var array2 = [
        { value: 1, text: 'example1' },
        { value: 2, text: 'example2' },
        { value: 3, text: 'example3' },
        { value: 4, text: 'example4' },
        { value: 5, text: 'example5' },
      ],
```

i want to display the text based on `arry1` delimited by commas something like below:

`example1,example2,example3`

how do I achieve that ?

```
var x = arry2.forEach(function(element, value){
        if (element.value == arry1){
          return element.value
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter `array2` and map the wanted property.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3],
    array2 = [{ value: 1, text: 'example1' }, { value: 2, text: 'example2' }, { value: 3, text: 'example3' }, { value: 4, text: 'example4' }, { value: 5, text: 'example5' }],
    result = array2
        .filter(({ value }) => array1.includes(value))
        .map(({ text }) => text);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your `array2` to an object of key-value pairs so that you can use the number stored at `value` to retrieve your `text` like so:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3]
const array2 = [{value: 1, text: 'example1'}, {value: 2, text: 'example2'}, {value: 3, text: 'example3'}, {value: 4, text: 'example4'}, {value: 5, text: 'example5'}];

const lut = array2.reduce((a, {value, text}) => ({...a, [value]:text}), {});
const res = array1.map(num_key => lut[num_key]).join() // loop through each number and then display it's associated text from the look-up-table we generated
console.log(res);
```

Comment: From my understanding, this solution has the best time complexity with O(n + m). Iterating while calling includes or indexOf on every step of an iteration like in other solutions comes around with O(n * m). This doesn't matter for small arrays like in this example but depending on the real data it might.

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` through each element in `arr1` to `find` the object in `arr2`, and use `join` to create a comma delimited string.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
var arr2 = [{value: 1,text: 'example1'},{value: 2,text: 'example2'},{value: 3,text: 'example3'},{value: 4,text: 'example4'},{value: 5,text: 'example5'}]

console.log(arr1.map(v => arr2.find(o => o.value === v).text).join(','))
```

Another way would be to use `reduce` with `includes`:

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
var arr2 = [{value: 1,text: 'example1'},{value: 2,text: 'example2'},{value: 3,text: 'example3'},{value: 4,text: 'example4'},{value: 5,text: 'example5'}]

console.log(arr2.reduce((a, {value, text}) => (arr1.includes(value) && a.push(text), a), []).join(','))
```

> NOTE: The first method will base the ordering from `arr1`, while the second method will base the ordering on `arr2`

The most efficient way, would be to use the first solution, according to this [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/includes-vs-find-vs-reduce/1):

[image: JSPerf]